# Prestashop 1.6 - Error price (schema.org)

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, schema.org, price

please help me.

I have Prestashop 1.6.1.7 and when I testing product page in Google Structured Data Testing Tool displays an error notice.

[Error notice picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p96Js.jpg)

Error is in price, I do not know what to do.

I searched on Google, but all posts are old.

```
<!-- prices -->
<div>
    <p class="our_price_display" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">{strip}
        {if $product->quantity > 0}<link itemprop="availability" href="https://schema.org/InStock"/>{/if}
        {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
                <span id="our_price_display" class="price" content="{$productPrice}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>
            {if $tax_enabled  && ((isset($display_tax_label) && $display_tax_label == 1) || !isset($display_tax_label))}
                {if $priceDisplay == 1} {l s='tax excl.'}{else} {l s='tax incl.'}{/if}
            {/if}
            <meta itemprop="price" content="{$productPrice}" />
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{$currency->iso_code}" />
            {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="price"}
        {/if}
    {/strip}</p>
    <p id="reduction_percent" {if $productPriceWithoutReduction <= 0 || !$product->specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'percentage'} style="display:none;"{/if}>{strip}
                <span id="reduction_percent_display">
                    {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'percentage'}-{$product->specificPrice.reduction*100}%{/if}
                </span>
            {/strip}</p>
    <p id="reduction_amount" {if $productPriceWithoutReduction <= 0 || !$product->specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'amount' || $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval ==0} style="display:none"{/if}>{strip}
        <span id="reduction_amount_display">
        {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'amount' && $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval !=0}
                -{convertPrice price=$productPriceWithoutReduction|floatval-$productPrice|floatval}
            {/if}
            </span>
        {/strip}</p>
        <p id="old_price"{if (!$product->specificPrice || !$product->specificPrice.reduction)} class="hidden"{/if}>{strip}
            {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
                {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="old_price"}
    <span id="old_price_display"><span class="price">{if $productPriceWithoutReduction > $productPrice}{convertPrice price=$productPriceWithoutReduction|floatval}{/if}</span>{if $productPriceWithoutReduction > $productPrice && $tax_enabled && $display_tax_label == 1} {if $priceDisplay == 1}{l s='tax excl.'}{else}{l s='tax incl.'}{/if}{/if}</span>
            {/if}
    {/strip}</p>
    {if $priceDisplay == 2}
        <br />
        <span id="pretaxe_price">{strip}
            <span id="pretaxe_price_display">{convertPrice price=$product->getPrice(false, $smarty.const.NULL)}</span> {l s='tax excl.'}
        {/strip}</span>
    {/if}
</div> <!-- end prices -->
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: the error can be seen in the picture.

I think that the error can be eliminated somewhere in the code that I sent. but I do not know where :(

Comment: Have you installed a custom template?

Comment: Yes, I have a custom teplate.

Comment: @BranislavHáz: My question was what you don’t understand about it / where your *specific* problem is. Stack Overflow is not the place to fix your code, it’s a place to answer your questions (and fixed code can be part of the answer).

Comment: Sorry, my English is poor.

I have 2 questions.

Question 1
Where and how do I add a property price, or priceSpecification? I think the error is in the code that I put. (Product.tpl)

Question 2
How do I specify a price for my property prices? Error is probably that Google does not support the price of €. And, if supported, I probably got an error that Google takes my cost and currency. And not separately.

Both errors are, in my line of code that I put above, but I do not know where to find out.

Please help me with my problem?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.